# Excel: How to sort a single column of mixed data into a table

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I have a list of payees, their bank number, my reference and their reference, in a column.

```
R & J Fred Ltd
12-3456-7890123-45
Freds Fish
Bevan
Joe King Mata Ltd
01-1234-1234567-89
Joes Boats
Bevan01
Dave's the Barber
12-3456-7891478-92
Daves Shaves
Accnt 45
```

and I want to make it into a table like this:

```
Payee              Account             MyRef        TheirRef
R & J Fred Ltd     12-3456-7890123-45  Freds Fish   Bevan
Joe King Mata Ltd  01-1234-1234567-89  Joes Boats   Bevan01
Dave's the Barber  12-3456-7891478-92  Daves Shaves Accnt 45
```

OK, so I have no idea how to get that into nice markdown for this site either, BTW :)

There's 300 rows of data, all in one column, following the same sequence all the way down the list.

I presume there's a simple way to do this but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the quickest or most elegant solution, but does get the desired result. This is based on the assumption that you data column is A, and the clean data will be in column B to E.

```
Sub Cleanmeup()
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Double, j As Double
lastrow = Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
i = 2
j = 2
For Each cel In Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    If i = 6 Then
        i = 2
        j = j + 1
    End If
    Cells(j, i).Value = cel
    i = i + 1
Next cel
End Sub
```